# Andy Murray's ranking at the beginning of 2018

Tags: tennis, international-sports, ranking

According to Andy Murray's Facebook page:

> Unfortunately, I won’t be able to compete in the upcoming events in Beijing and Shanghai, and most likely, the final two events to finish the season in Vienna and Paris due to my hip injury which has been bothering me the last few months.
>   Having consulted with a number of leading hip specialists over the last week, along with my own team, we have decided that this is the best decision for my long-term future.

Given Andy Murray's success in these tournaments last year, I'd imagine his withdrawal from these tournaments is going to be detrimental to his ranking.

So, what could be a tentative ranking Andy Murray reemerges at to start the 2018 Australian Open swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the best way to determine his ranking would be to compare his position with another player who has ran the course in a similar situation, and see what ranking the player had at the beginning of the Australian Open swing. The player I will be comparing with Andy Murray (later half of 2017) is Roger Federer (second half of 2016).

The similarities between these two players which make them ideal to compare are as follows:

Both Federer and Murray withdrew from their half of the year in  the same spot in the ATP rankings: Federer- on [July 26th, 2016](http://www.stevegtennis.com/men-atp-rankings/2016-07-25/1/all/) was ranked "3" in the world with a point total of 5945, Murray on [September 6th, 2017](http://live-tennis.eu/en/atp-live-ranking) was ranked "3" in the world with a point total of 6790.

Both players will have lost similar point totals going into each's AO swing-

Roger Federer did not defend point totals in: Cincinnati (1000), U.S Open (1200), Shanghai (10), Basel (500), Paris (90), ATP World Tour Finals (1090) = [-3890 points going into 2017 Australian Open swing](http://www.atpworldtour.com/players/roger-federer/f324/player-activity?year=2015).

Andy Murray will most likely not defend point totals in: Beijing (500), Shanghai (1000), Vienna (500), Paris (1000), ATP World Tour Finals (1500)= [-4500 points going into 2018 Australian Open swing](http://www.atpworldtour.com/players/andy-murray/mc10/player-activity?year=2016).

This would put each's point total going into the swings at - Roger Federer 2130, and Andy Murray at 2290.

Because of these two criteria, we can make an informed judgement that if we were to estimate Andy Murray's ranking going into the 2018 Australian Open swing, he will be somewhere between **16-20** in the Emirates ATP Rankings. The +4 margin in rankings is largely based on the 160 point total difference between Murray and Federer for each's respective year. Roger Federer started the 2017 AO swing [ranked 16](http://www.stevegtennis.com/men-atp-rankings/2017-01-02/1/all/).

Comment: Yes, this seems to be correct prediction, [this dailymail article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/tennis/article-4858920/Is-beginning-end-Andy-Murray.html) predicts 17 while [this metro article](http://metro.co.uk/2017/09/07/boris-becker-thinks-andy-murray-should-follow-roger-federers-lead-in-2018-6911821/) predicts 15.